# How are HTML elements passed into angularjs compile and linking functions?

Tags: dom, angularjs, directive

How are HTML elements passed into angularjs compile and linking functions? Looking at them in the console, it looks like they arn't native HTML elements. Is it jquery or a lighter version of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's jqlite unless you include jquery before.
http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

In the angular code (and docs) they also say:

Angular's jQuery lite provides the following methods (v1.0.6):

- [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)Limited to lookups by tag name.
- [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)
- [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)
- [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [removeData()](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/)
- [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)
- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)Doesn't pass native event objects to handlers.
- [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
- [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)